How to renew kerberos ticket on a non-ad member?
My computer is not a member of the domain.
I have used kinit to fetch a Kerberos that I use to mount CIFS shares.
After the expiration, I got a lstat filePathName : required key not available error so I had to ask for a new ticket again with kinit.
I tried this krenew command but it did not work :
$ screen -L -Logfile kerberos_renew-$(date +%Y%m%d).txt krenew -K 10 -v
$

How can renew my kerberos tickets automatically ?
